# Android Studio: How to download expansion files and upload to Google play

Tags: java, android-studio, google-play, apk

My app is finished and ready to upload! The problem is it's 432Mb. Google play says my app can't be over 100Mb and I should use an expansion file. I have a general idea of what that is, but feel free to break it down. What I need from you is steps on how to get my expansion files and upload it with my APK to Google play. I'm working with 5 mp3 files at 83MB each.

Comment: Read: https://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html. Unfortunately there are a lot of steps and limitations so you'll have to take your time to understand them. No one knows how you wrote your app so only you can figure it out. But when you have a specific question, then ask on StackOverflow. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks, it looked a little overbearing, but I'm slowly reading through!

Comment: One solution would to be to store the MP3 files online and download them when you start the app... Or compress them. Or both.

Comment: How do I do that?